# IFC geometry - Space Boundaries

Tags: user-interface, geometry, revit, ifc, bim

Can anyone recommend an appropriate forum for asking questions about Industry Foundation Class geometry?

I am parsing IFC and interpreting the geometry, focussing on space boundaries.(IFCRELSPACEBOUNDARY)

All the space boundaries associated with a particular space are offset by a certain distance.  The offset distance is different for different spaces.  The 6 faces of a specimen 6-sided space fit together perfectly - but these faces do not even begin to fit with the adjacent space. What am I missing?

The IFC has been generated using the Alternative IFC GUI in Revit using IFC Coordination View 2.0 using IFC 2x3_TC1 schema with the option to export 2nd level space boundaries.

I am aware that there are tools for interpreting IFC files in java e.g. IFC Tools Project, but I am using Python for the developmental stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to FreeCAD people or IFCOpenshell mailing list. They are helpful for your queries.
http://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/index.php?title=Arch_IFC

Answer (score 1):

When you have an offset in an object of your IFC file, it is most likely due to the object placement of one of it's spatial containers (i.e. IfcProject, IfcSite, IfcBuilding, IfcBuildingStorey). Every IFC object has to be placed inside the spatial containment tree and so it inherits the offset of the site, building, storey, etc. (See the entire tree: IfcSpatialStructureElement) You need to check all spatial structure elements that contain your object (containment relation is defined by the entity IfcRelAggregates) and look for the attribute called 'ObjectPlacement'. ObjectPlacement takes one instance of the entity IfcAxis2Placement3D, this is where the offset is defined. I hope this helps to know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I have subsequently identified 2 issues here.

1. IfcSite is offset from the origin as defined by IfcLocalPlacement.
2. Revit generated correctly located space boundaries when the unit system was set to decimal feet.

Problem solved.

Any suggestions regarding a suitable forum to post IFC related questions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the 'Industry Foundation Classes (IFC)' group on LinkedIn.